Build AOSP 13 for tablet emulator
What should be the lunch target to build AOSP 13 code for tablet emulator
I can launch phone emulator using lunch target sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebg.
But I want to build AOSP for tablet emulator

I think it's the same image, but different skin.
That is, the tablet layout is determined by the size of the screen, not by a dedicated image.
Therefore I would try:

build AOSP as usual for  sdk_phone_x86_64-userdebug
Crate a new avd based on the system image you've built, with the appropriate display size avdmanager ... -skin 1080x1920 ... if the existing skins don't meet your requirements, you can create a new one, following the format here


thanks, I was able to change make tablet layout using "emulator -skin 1920x1080 -wipe-data" additionaly after decreasing density using "adb shell wm density " it looks as tablet perfectly.

@Margishthumar that's great , would appreciate if you could accept the answer then :))
